Instagram private API - Max Besties Exceeded, Error While Adding Followers to Close Friends List
I'm working with the instagram-private-api to add followers to the close friends list using the setBesties method. Everything works fine until I reach 9,999 followers, but as soon as I try to add more beyond this number, I receive the following error:
Retry failed: IgResponseError: POST /api/v1/friendships/set_besties/ - 400 Bad Request; max besties exceeded
    at Request.handleResponseError (C:\Users\hamza\Desktop\instagram-close-friends-automation-ts\node_modules\instagram-private-api\src\core\request.ts:172:12)
    at Request.send (C:\Users\hamza\Desktop\instagram-close-friends-automation-ts\node_modules\instagram-private-api\src\core\request.ts:83:24)
    at async FriendshipRepository.setBesties (C:\Users\hamza\Desktop\instagram-close-friends-automation-ts\node_modules\instagram-private-api\src\repositories\friendship.repository.ts:76:22)

Here's the part of the code where the error occurs:
await ig.friendship.setBesties({ add: batch, remove: [] });
Below is the function I am using to add users to close friends list.
// Function to add followers to the close friends list
async function addToCloseFriends(ig: IgApiClient, followerIds: string[], batchSize: number, requestDelay: number, batchDelay: number) {
    let totalAdded = 0;
    console.log(`Adding ${followerIds.length} followers to close friends list...`);
    for (let i = 0; i < followerIds.length; i += batchSize) {
        const batch = followerIds.slice(i, i + batchSize);
        try {
            await ig.friendship.setBesties({ add: batch, remove: [] });
            totalAdded += batch.length;
            console.log(`Added batch ${Math.floor(i / batchSize) + 1} to close friends. Total added: ${totalAdded}`);
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, requestDelay))
        } catch (error) {
            if (error instanceof IgNotFoundError) {
                console.error('An API endpoint was not found:', error.message);
            } else {
                console.error('An error occurred while adding to close friends:', error);
            }
            break;
        }
    
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, batchDelay));
    }
    console.log('All followers have been added to the close friends list.');

Everything works without any issue until 9999 followers are added, but after that, I consistently get the 400 Bad Request error.
And there isnt any limit on how many close friends you can add to your list. I have seen peaople added over 50K followers.
I tested smaller batches and larger batches, but the error consistently appeared once I hit the 9,999 follower limit. I attempted to check the API documentation to see if this limit was mentioned but couldn't find anything explicit about a cap on the number of users in the close friends list.
If there's a hidden cap of 9,999, I'd like to know if it's possible to extend or bypass this limit, or if there’s any other solution that allows managing a larger number of users as "besties" on Instagram.

Hello ! Your question includes your answer. 400 Bad Request; max besties exceeded, there is a limit to how many besties you can have. If you want to bypass this limit you might have to take a look at you instgram account configuration if you can specify something. But I reckon there is not much possible to do on the code side

@GregoireDucharme I understand that there’s a limit on the number of besties if we see according to code perspective, but I've seen people  who have successfully added over 50k+ followers to their close friends list through script. If there isn’t much that can be done in the code, do you know of any alternative strategies or configurations that might allow for this?

I have never use instgram API so I have no precise idea how you might by pass this.You should ask instagram API support or look through their FAQ if the have one
